dpdk ipsec with multi process application
I am interested to do ipsec encoding and decoding in my dpdk application
From my readings, i understand ipsec can be done in a single call in the nic (inline ipsec) synchronously or with multiple calls (rte_cryptodev_enqueue_burst, rte_cryptodev_dequeue_burst....)

If ipsec is done by nic I only need to call rte_ipsec_pkt_process(...) without other functions?
I use  rte_eth_rx_burst to read from nic.

Where do I see list of nic that support nic inline ipsec? I believe not all dpdk nic support it.

How much does it impact performance ? is there a table of performance per nic?

My application is multi process, but the read from nic is only one thread per nic, the mbuf is passed to other threads in pipeline. I can see in documentation :
“Currently, the security library does not support the case of multi-process. It will be updated in the future releases.” From https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_security.html



So ipsec also is not supported for multi process application? Or is the problem only with multi queue?
Even if done inline by the nic?
And what about non inline ipsec for multi process applications?


Is ip sec also supported in multi queue with rte flow in the inline ipsec ?

